# Why is the Adobe PDF Control not opening outside debugging? (Error 103)

Tags: c#, pdf, adobe, activex

I'm using the ActiveX Adobe PDF Viewer Control (AxAcroPDFLib.AxAcroPDF) from Adobe Reader XI.

I load the PDF File with `axAcroPDF1.LoadFile(_pdffile);`

Everything **works well in VisualStudio** with debugger. But when I start the compiled EXE file, no PDF opens. Also tried with Administrator privileges. The area of the control is grey and after a while the error message

> There is a problem with Adobe Acrobat/Reader. If it is running, please exit and try again. (103:103)

appears.
I tried to disable the 'Protected Mode at startup' and I reinstalled Adobe Reader. But doesn't work!

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you find any solution for your problem as I am facing the same issue on my end.

Comment: i switched to [foxit](https://developers.foxitsoftware.com/pdf-sdk/windows/net/)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my application and this worked for me:

1. Go to Adobe=>Edit=>Preferences=>Security(Enhanced)
2. Uncheck both "Enable protected mode at startup" and "Enable Enhanced Security"

Thats it! Hope it works for you/other in the future.
[image]

Comment: I had this repeated problem a couple of weeks later. The fix was to reinstall acrobat reader on both machines, development and client, since there might have been a version conflict.